# php auto logout session in url friendly .html

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, authentication, url-rewriting

i change my `.php` page to `.html` for url friendly Or `page.php?id=10` to `page/id/title` using mod_rewrite and php. now i have Big problem, when i login in my panel if login page action = login.php login success and i see user panel but if login page action = login.html i auto logouted. i check for index page . what's my problem?! thanks

example 1 Worked : this logined and work

```
http://mydomain.com/subfolder/index.php  
http://mydomain.com/subfolder/page.php?id=10
http://mydomain.com/subfolder/login.php
http://mydomain.com/subfolder/profile.php
```

example 1 NotWorked : this not login and not work

```
http://mydomain.com/subfolder/
http://mydomain.com/subfolder/page/10/title
http://mydomain.com/subfolder/login.html
http://mydomain.com/subfolder/profile.html
```

.htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^login\.html$ login.php
RewriteRule ^profile\.html$ profile.php
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

***NOTE*** : This Worked In My xampp Localhost but not worked in really web host.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse .html (or files with any other extention) using PHP, the easiest way is to just tell Mr. Apache! please tell your friend, Mr. PHP to take a look at my .html files!!!
If you're loading php as an apache module, you can do this with a little change on your httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module "D:/PHP5.3.0/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html .any-extention
```

Comment: in localhost i dont have any problem. Confusing the issue : why not work with my index !

Comment: And My hosting support : No, it is not possible. i dont access for edited this !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to write PHP and have it displayed or run correctly, you must have the file extension .php, or any other supported PHP extension.
Having .html or .htm will not work. The PHP in the file is ultimately ignored as invalid syntax and is henceforth pointless to write PHP in HTML files.

Comment: your mean is: if user logined in systems! cant see any page with seo user friendly url ?! this is my seo friendly url : `http://mydomain.com/subfolder/page/10/title` shen user see this auto logouted.

Comment: Reiterate with better grammars?

Comment: This is not true: as the other answer shows, you can simply tell Apache to send .html files to the PHP processor

Comment: Obviously there are exceptions to every rule.